# Can a Java Factory class be structured to instantiate either Java 6 or Java 7 specific class based on JVM version?

Tags: java, java-7

Java 7 can run Java 6 code, but Java 6 can't run Java 7-specific code (e.g. NIO 2.0).  I want to support users using either JVM, but give Java 7 users additional functionality.

Is it possible to build a Factory class with Java 6 using an interface such that it can conditionally instantiate a Java 6 compiled class if the JVM is 1.6 or a Java 7 compiled class if the JVM is Java 7?

E.g. something like:

```
String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
if (javaVersion.startsWith("1.6")) {
    myInterface = Class.forName("com.project.java6.MyInterfaceImplementation").newInstance();
} 
else {
    myInterface = Class.forName("com.project.java7.MyInterfaceImplementation").newInstance();
}
```

If so, would the two versions need to be packaged in separate jars, one for the Java 6 compiled code and the other for the Java 7 code?

Comment: What happened when you tested your code?

Comment: If I use the -source and -target options in the build, it will run but gets a warning during the build.  If I don't use those flags, it gets a UnsupportedClassVersionError unsupported major.minor version 51.0 unable to load class.  I want a solution that will build without warnings and run without Exceptions/Errors.

Comment: You can always use, say, `Class.forName("java.nio.Files");`, if it fails you know you use Java 6

Comment: Checking the "java.version" works fine for me for the check so I don't understand what that gains me?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without having to worry about the versions.  You can even build the "Java 7" to run on Java 6, but won't work because it needs classes which are not there. i.e. you can have one JAR which runs in Java 6 for them all.  Also you don't need to use reflection.

Comment: I would like to see more extended answer

Comment: If I don't use the 'forName', then I get:   warning: .\classes\com\project\java7\MyInterfaceImplementation.class: major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
1 warning   -- if I build the factory with Java 6, or the "unable to load class" if I build the factory with Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

By trying different methods, I found two ways to do this without incurring any warnings:

Build Java 7 implementations with Java 7.  Build the rest with Java 6.  Instantiate the Java 7 code using forName and newInstance.

Build all code using Java 7 with the following compiler options '-source 1.6 -target 1.6 -bootclasspath [Java 7 path]/lib/rt.jar'.  All code gets the Java 6 major version of 50, including the code using the Java 7 methods.  In this case, the Java 6 code can instantiate the implementation classes directly as Peter stated.

In the first case, the reflection defers the class from being loaded until we know we are using Java 7.  In the second case, the classes using Java 7 have the right major code so can be loaded under either JVM, but the Java 7-specific methods are only invoked if running Java 7.